# Providing compression at page level for multipage tiff

Tags: java, tiff, image-compression

Can I provide compression at page level rathar than image level in multipage tiff using java ?
The below code is setting compression in all the pages of result.tiff.

TIFFEncodeParam params = new TIFFEncodeParam();

params.setCompression(TIFFEncodeParam.COMPRESSION_GROUP4);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("E:/Images/result.tiff");

ImageEncoder encoder = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("tiff", out, params);

I want seperate compressions in seperate pages (one of the compressions is JPEG compression also)

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can if you use are willing to use third party software see https://github.com/dragon66/icafe